# how to create customize textchanged event in aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia

textchanged event Consumer should pass event and not in control.Consumer will excute their code on textchange event. Component will just expose that event. ???
this is requirement how can I create in aurelia?

component

## textbox.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control change.delegate="inputValueChange()">
```

## textbox.ts

```
constructor() {

  }

  attached() {
    this.controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.changeOrBlur;
    this.controller.addRenderer(new BootstrapFormRenderer());
    this.controller.validate();
   } 

    public inputValueChange(newValue,oldValue){
      console.log(newValue)
      }
    }
```

## app.html

```
<template>
<textbox  maxlength="10" autocomplete="on"></textbox>
<template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom events - in your textbox component add this to the constructor:

```
constructor(private element: Element) {}
```

and in the inputValueChange add something like this:

```
let event = new CustomEvent('textchange', { 
        detail: <some-data-you-want-to-send>,
        bubbles: true
    });

this.element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You should then be able to use the new textchange event like this:

```
<textbox  maxlength="10" autocomplete="on" textchange.delegate="someFunction()"></textbox>
```

PS! in your example you are missing a " after the form-control / before change.delegate, that will probably prevent the inputValueChange from being called at all now

Comment: how do you get the `detail` in `someFunction`? I see you passed no arguments to it. In case to have `<some-data-you-want-to-send>`, how would you get that in your handler?

Comment: @IonelLupu you should be able to add $event, i.e. textchange.delegate="someFunction($event)", and then in the someFunction add a parameter called event. Then event.detail should contain the data